# PM2 start not working with socketi in AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I am trying to deploy the soketi in aws elastic beanstalk to run in background with pm2
my bash file contains as

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/app/current/
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g @soketi/soketi
sudo npm install -g pm2
pm2 start soketi -- start --config=/var/app/current/my_soketi/config.json
```

the script work and install all the requirement without any error
by when write the command

```
pm2 status
```

it is not give that the soketi is running on the list

[image]

when i run the command manuallyin EC2 it's working

```
pm2 start soketi -- start --config=/var/app/current/my_soketi/config.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should write

```
sudo pm2 status
```

[image]